# Google GYP to MSVC Solution

Tags: c++, visual-studio, projects-and-solutions

How can I create a MSVC solution from a Google GYP File? There seems to be limited documentation on this ...

Comment: See http://code.google.com/p/gyp/wiki/GypLanguageSpecification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation is now more valid and this question is no longer needed.